# How to disable fuelux datepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, fuelux

I am using fuelux wizard on a page which already uses bootstrap-datepicker.  The presence of fuelux breaks the other datepicker.  Is there any way to tell fuelux to only include 'wizard' control functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special build GUI, but you can include individual control JS files. They are just jQuery plugins. Look at the JS folder. Some have dependencies, but wizard doesn't.

You can limit the CSS cascade with the `.fuelux` class.